# Difference between $1, ${1} and $"1" in awk

Tags: awk, parameter

While working on a script, the following script gave an error

```
file * | awk '{ ${1}=""; print substr(${0},2) }';
```

while both of the following scripts ran successfully

```
file * | awk '{ $"1"=""; print substr($"0",2) }';
```

and

```
file * | awk '{ $1=""; print substr($0,2) }';
```

Aren't `$1, ${1}, $"1"` all parameter substitution? Is there a problem with my `awk` syntax?

Comment: Note that one of the reasons the curly braces are not used under awk but required under the shell is when the positional parameter is larger than 9. Under the shell `$10` is `$1` immediately followed by the letter `0` while under `awk`, it's the tenth field.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`awk` is not the shell. `awk` has its own grammar, syntax and semantics. `${1}` is not syntactically correct `awk` code while both `$1` and `$"1"` are (and these are equivalent in `awk`). In `awk`, these are not substitutions.

With `awk`, `$1` refers to the first field of the current input record and `$0` refers to the complete input record, while in the shell, `$1` refers to the first positional parameter (usually the first argument on the command line of a script or function) and `$0` usually refers to the name of the current shell or shell script.

Shell variables and `awk` variables are also completely separate. This is why `awk` has the `-v` command line flag to set its variables if you need to "import" a value from the shell to your `awk` script:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" '{...}'
```

You may also give an `awk` script a the value of a shell variable like this:

```
$ awk '{...}' var="$var"
```

This is *almost* the same thing as doing it with `-v` except that the variable `var` will be empty in any `BEGIN` block.  A `BEGIN` block is executed *before* looking at the input data, and the variable is set *after* the execution of such a block.

You can also do

```
$ awk '{...}' var="$value1" file1 var="$value2" file2
```

This makes the `var` variable get the value of the shell variable `$value1` just before `file1` is being processed, and then the value of the shell variable `$value2` just before `file2` is being processed.

If any *file* has the name `var="$value1"` in the last example (for example `var="42"`, which is a perfectly legal Unix filename), that file will *not* be processed. Also if a shell filename globbing pattern on the command line picks up a file whose name looks like an assignment to a variable, this assignment will be active in the `awk` script.

Comment: Also `$ 1`, `$(0+2/2)`, `$ length("a")`. It's important to realise `$` is an operator, not a parameter introducer like in shells.

Comment: One should avoid `-v` to _import variables from the shell_, as it mangles the values if they contain backslashes. Using the environment and the `ENVIRON` special hash in `awk` is preferable.

Comment: FWIW, `$ "1st field"` would also work or any string that yields  1 when converted to a number (like in `print "1st field" + 0`)

Comment: Replying to myself, actually it seems `$ "1st field"` is like `$1` everywhere _except in GNU awk_. Looking at the POSIX spec, it's not clear what that or `$"1"` are meant to yield. The gawk behaviour seems buggy to me. Compare `echo a b | awk '{print $("" "1st")}'` and `echo a b | awk '{print $("1st")}'` for instance.

Comment: Looking at the git HEAD of `gawk`, `$"1"` no longer works there actually.

Comment: I just raised the question on the austin-group mailing list https://www.mail-archive.com/austin-group-l@opengroup.org/msg01543.html